# POVRay code not highlighted minted

Tags: minted

Bonjour !
I want to highlight PovRay code with minted but I don't get any result !
PovRay is in the list of pygments language supported, and I run my file with -enable -write18 in windows vista 64 bit (MiKTeX 2.9). With C,C++,Python,... no problem

Any advice ?

I get error (screenshot):

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4 paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}


\begin{minted}{POVRay}   

camera { 
location <-3,7,-15>
look_at <0,1,0>
} 

 light_source {
<3,7,-10>
rgb <1,1,0.1>
}
plane {
y
0
pigment {   rgb <1,1,1>}
 }
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pygments lexer list](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) gives `pov` as the short name for the `PovrayLexer`. Switching to `\begin{minted}{pov}...` should give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I compile with pov as you have write me  without success !